# Autocomplete places widget returning error on place tap

Tags: flutter

[Places Autocomplete widget returns this exception error when a place is tapped in prediction list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2FLK.png)

Answer (score 0):

getDetailsByPlaceId returns a dynamic List. Change the return type to `List<PlaceDetails>`.

```dart
List<PlaceDetails> getDetailsByPlaceId(String id) { //Or whatever parameter you use
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that when you call the getPlacesbyId method so there is the return value it is expecting the list but  it is getting the list of dynamic, So you need to make a return type of your List so the error might be resolved.